# find $f(\frac{1}{2014})+f(\frac{2}{2014})+.....+f(\frac{2013}{2014})$ of $f(x)=\frac{2}{2+4^x}$

Tags: functions, quadratics

$f(x)=\frac{2}{2+4^x}$ 
find
$f(\frac{1}{2014})+f(\frac{2}{2014})+.....+f(\frac{2013}{2014})$

Please guide me through it, the only step I know is probably to eliminate the denominator
ps. Not a homework

Answer (score 5):

HINT:

$$f(1-x)=\dfrac2{2+4^{1-x}}=\dfrac{2\cdot4^x}{2\cdot4^x+4}=\dfrac{4^x}{4^x+2}=\dfrac{4^x+2-2}{4^x+2}=1-f(x)$$

Set $x=\dfrac r{2014}, 1\le r\le2013$ and add

Comment: I am sorry but I am still confused

Comment: I am sorry but I am still confused

Comment: @DeepJ, Please pinpoint your confusion.

Comment: Where should I insert the x to

Comment: the $1-f(x)$? or the $\frac{4^x+2-2}{4^x+2}&

Comment: @DeepJ, So, we have $$f(x)+f(1-x)=1$$ right?

Comment: yes, so it is just 1+1+1+.... ?

Comment: @DeepJ, But how many :)

Comment: 1006? is it correct? 1006,5?